# Do I need an adapter to mount a Sigma lens to a Canon Rebel Ti3?

Tags: lens, sigma, canon-1100d

I bought a Sigma 70-300mm  DG 4-5.6 Macro Zoom Lens for  my Canon Rebel T3. Do I need an adapter of some sort to be able to attach the lens to my camera?

Answer (score 4):

Sigma produces same lenses for many different mounts, such as Canon, Nikon, Sony, Pentax, micro 4/3, etc... If you bought Sigma lens for Canon, than you don't need an adapter. If you didn't... well, why didn't you? It might be possible to attach it with adapter, and might not. but that depends on the particular mount your lens *is* compatible with (for example you may adapt Nikon lens to Canon, but not the other way around).

Comment: I bought the lens on eBay the seller said it was for a cannon EOS camera. However it will not go on my camera. Do I'm thinking it's not made with the cannon mount

Comment: I found online that the lens I bought isade for a sony camera is there an adapter that will allow it to fit on my cannon

Comment: @Beckgurl You might want to include photos of the lens mount and camera's body mount so that people can easier recognize the mounts and see what can be done.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in cases like this, it is probably a better decision to return a misadvertised lens than to go messing with adapters.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps your lens was of the manual focus AE 35mm Sigma vintage, not compatible with AF Canon cameras without an adapter?

Comment: Unsure how your answer applies. OP states that their lens is a Sigma 70-300mm DG 4-5.6 Macro Zoom Lens. Sig makes lenses with different mounts so as to not need adapters. (most of their lenses come in the Canon/Nikon/Sigma mount variants)